# Zoom camera FOV overtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm wondering how to smoothly zoom in and smoothly zoom out on button press in Unity3d using c#. I've got zooming part down already, but not sure how to make a transition of zooming in and out smooth. As an example, I'd like it to zoom in as smooth as it is in ARMA or DayZ game.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class zoomIN : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera cam;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButton (1)) {
            cam.fieldOfView = 20;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (1)) {
            cam.fieldOfView = 60;
        }

    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help!
Thanks and Merry Xmas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use coroutine to do this. You can use it to enable the speed or duration of the zooming. Perform a `Mathf.Lerp` between `cam.fieldOfView` and the destination( `20` or `60`) depending on if the key is pressed or released.

Note: You must change `Input.GetMouseButton` to `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` otherwise your first `if` statement will be running every frame while the right mouse button is held down. I think you want to be true **once** only.

```
public Camera cam;
Coroutine zoomCoroutine;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        //Stop old coroutine
        if (zoomCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(zoomCoroutine);

        //Start new coroutine and zoom within 1 second
        zoomCoroutine = StartCoroutine(lerpFieldOfView(cam, 20, 1f));
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
    {
        //Stop old coroutine
        if (zoomCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(zoomCoroutine);

        //Start new coroutine and zoom within 1 second
        zoomCoroutine = StartCoroutine(lerpFieldOfView(cam, 60, 1f));
    }

}


IEnumerator lerpFieldOfView(Camera targetCamera, float toFOV, float duration)
{
    float counter = 0;

    float fromFOV = targetCamera.fieldOfView;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;

        float fOVTime = counter / duration;
        Debug.Log(fOVTime);

        //Change FOV
        targetCamera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(fromFOV, toFOV, fOVTime);
        //Wait for a frame
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again pal, appreciate it.

Comment: Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to get your smooth zoom animation is by performing the zoom operation over multiple frames. So instead of changing the `fieldOfView` from 20 to 60 right away, increase the `fieldOfView` with 5 every frame until you reach your target of 60. (To lengthen the animation you can of course take a smaller number than 5.) So based on the mouse input you can keep a state `_zoomedIn` and based on that state and on the current `fieldOfView` you can determine whether you still need to add or substract to the value. Which gives you something like the following code: (not tested)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class zoomIN : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera cam;
    private bool _zoomedIn = false;
    private int _zoomedInTarget = 60;
    private int _zoomedOutTarget = 20;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (1))
            _zoomedIn = true;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (1)) {
            _zoomedIn = false;
        }

        if (_zoomedIn) {
            if (cam.fieldOfView < _zoomedInTarget)
                cam.fieldOfView += 5;
        } else {
            if (cam.fieldOfView > _zoomedOutTarget)
                cam.fieldOfView -= 5;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seem to be exactly what I'm looking for. But there's a small issue. When the game starts, it starts as zoomed in already. But after clicking right mouse it goes back to normal and then works just fine. I tried using _zoomedIO = false; in Start function but it doesn't seem to be doing that for some reason. Wtf am I doing wrong? lol

Thanks in advance by the way.